# Pushing Content with Chakra-UI Drawer Component

Tags: css, reactjs, chakra-ui

I am learning how to use the Chakra-UI drawer component:  https://chakra-ui.com/docs/overlay/drawer.  It basically does everything I want it to, with one exception -- it covers the content instead of pushing it to the side.  What I want is a right side drawer that when it opens pushes the content to the left.

Is this possible with the Chakra-UI Drawer component?  If so, how can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this solution but you can try This

1.Don't Use Drawer.

2.Instead of drawer create a one component called custom Drawer(you can name `enter code here`any) that have stuff which you required

In custom Drawer write some css for parent element class name will be  as follow and class Name Will Accept By Props

```css
.displayNone{
    display:none
}
```

```css
.displayNone{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:400px
    overflowX:scroll
}
```

3.Now By Conditional Rendering of components you have to pass following components

I.

```
<customeDrawer class="displayNone"><customeDrawer>
```

II.

```
<customeDrawer class="displayBlock"><customeDrawer>
```

Hope So It Will UseFull

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was to set `padding-right: 0 !important` to the `body`.